# Android onDraw() method and adding images

Tags: android, xml, ondraw

I have a view where i have overriden the onDraw() function for animation purposes. However there are some images i would to like to be static in the view do i have to draw these images in the onDraw() function as well or can i apply these images via XML or something as a template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only override the onDraw() method of the views you want to draw by yourself. Otherwise you have to paint them yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a frame layout, which would have a child view for your static image and a child view for your animated images. Otherwise, I think you would have to redraw it each time. 
Also don't forget about other [animation methods](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html)